# Use the phone stylus/digitizer as a PC input method

Tags: windows, usb-drivers, input-methods, stylus

I would like to use my Samsung Note; taking advantage of its digitizer; as a input device of the desktop pc.

I suppose the question/answer can also apply to other brands and the touch screen.

Is it possible?

is there any driver/app necessary?

is it not possible due any Android OS restriction?

Comment: There are apps in Play Store which can turn your phone into a trackpad. I have used KDEConnect in past and I remember briefly using this feature *et al*. Is that what you are after?

Comment: Good idea, I was on "tunnel focus" mode , and just thinking in emulate  wacom tablets,drivers and so on.